# How to verify feature staus (enabled/disbaled) using client object model in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom, features

I am working on "Retrieving activated features of specific scope".

I have written following code.

```
        ClientContext context = ContextManager.GetClientContext(cred, siteUrl);
        Site site = null;
        Web web = null;
        Guid featureID = Guid.Empty;
        FeatureCollection activatedFeatures;

        Office365Helper.GetSiteAndWeb(context, out site, out web);

            if (isSiteCollection)
            {
                activatedFeatures = site.Features;
                scope = "Site";
            }
            else
            {
                activatedFeatures = web.Features;
                scope = "Web";
            }

            context.Load(activatedFeatures);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            try
            {
                Feature feature = null;
                string tempString = string.Empty;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(featureId))
                {
                    context.Load(activatedFeatures, gotFeature => gotFeature.Include(myfeature => myfeature.DisplayName, myfeature => myfeature.DefinitionId));
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    featureID = activatedFeatures.FirstOrDefault(gotFeature => gotFeature.DisplayName.Equals(featureTitle, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).DefinitionId;
                    feature = activatedFeatures.GetById(featureID);
                }
                else
                {
                    featureID = new Guid(featureId);
                    feature = activatedFeatures.GetById(featureID);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Error occured while trying to retrive the feature '{0}' from the site collection '{1}'. Error: {2}", featureTitle, siteUrl, ex.Message), ex);
            }
```

Now using site.Features or web.Features I am retrieving all the features. But I want to retrieve only activated features.

Is there any other method available to get only activated features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Features property only returns Features that have been activated.

[Web.Features property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.features.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Rob. My problem is solved now.
By the way do we have any way to get list of all features (whether enabled or disabled)?

Using SharePoint Object Model we can get it by `SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions` , so do we have any similar way for Client object model?

Comment: No, as far as I know you can't do that